# 64-Bit VB.NET Allocating > 2GB of RAM (.NET bug?)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, memory, 64-bit

I have a 64 bit VB.NET application and want to allocate a buffer > 2GB in size.

In the following code both the "new" and the "ReDim" throw an "OverflowException."

How can I allocate buffers > 2GB when these functions only accept signed 32 bit values?

(Is this possible in C#?)

**Edit** - I am running WinXP 64 with 4GB of RAM.

```
Dim width As Long = 19005
Dim height As Long = 32768

Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte((width * height * 4) - 1) {}

Dim size As Long = (width * height * 4) - 1
ReDim buffer(size)
```

Comment: How do you know it's a 64-bit application? How does it show up in the process viewer (if you arrange to have it running long enough)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to allocate more than 2GB even under 64 bit .net application running on a 64 bit OS.

I find this to be very disappointing and completely without regard for what 64 bit applications and OSs are made for.  I am dealing with *gigantic* images and would like to be able to work with the raw bytes all in RAM at once.  Now I have to implement paging algorithms to limit the chunks to 2GB.

Hey Microsoft, hows abouts you fix this in the coming .NET release?  Yes, I said *fix.*  That's because it's broken.  How do you expect 64 bit applications to take off when you do *stupid* things like this. (Can you tell that I am *annoyed*.) Thanks for listening.

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx)

http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: If you read closely, that isn't exactly true.  He even provides 2 viable solutions.

Comment: It *is* true that you can't allocate more than 2GB using the .net new / redim functions.  Where do you see that it isn't true.  The alternatives are more work and should at least in theory be completely unnecessary.

Comment: That "Big Array" class looks suspect to me and I wouldn't use it if you paid me.  The custom memory allocator like Paint.NET might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think the UnmanagedMemoryStream does what you need. [MSDN doc for UnmanagedMemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream(VS.100).aspx)

I think it's a bad idea, to allocate a huge chunk of memory in a garbage collected environment, since most garbage collectors are optimized for small & short lived object. So using raw memory is generally a better and more performant solution for very large objects.

Comment: It seems to still be limited to 2GB as it takes an "integer" (32 bit signed) argument.

Comment: Yes. It takes int32 when reading and writing, but the constructor takes 64bit integers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267517(VS.100).aspx

Comment: It's also not available for Visual Basic as "Visual Basic does not support APIs that consume or return unsafe types."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw66yex7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following works [in theory] (C# syntax):

```
Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), 0L);
```

Edit: Make a type with a fixed-size allocated array of 1GB arrays. You can re-index in the Item property via a shift.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use memory mapped files for this, take a look at the [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761%28VS.85%29.aspx)  function.